# How to load a SD Grid and scroll automatically to last record on Genexus 15?

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd

I have a SD grid to show messages received from other users (a simple chat app) and every time I open this panel, the first records appears and I have to manually scroll to reach last message.

Is there a way to automatically go to last record on this grid  ?

I know there is a Select() method on grids, but this can´t be used on Refresh Event, only on user events.

I´m using GX15 U6

Thanks,
Rogelio Arosemena

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with [Inverse Loading](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?32660,Inverse%20Loading%20property) property

> This property is available for grids in the Smart Devices generator.
>
> By setting it to True (its default value is False), the developer will
>   be able to load the grid in reverse direction (i.e. the Common Grid
>   will be loaded from bottom to top, and the Horizontal Grid will be
>   loaded from right to left).
>
> Example of use The canonical use case of inverse loading on a grid is
>   that of a chat messaging system. What are its characteristics? It is
>   loaded from bottom to top, pagination is performed with a swipe-down
>   gesture, and when the user refreshes it the first page will be
>   displayed in the lower section.

Comment: Unfortunately once it is reviewed by me, I can't "undo" the review.  But so far I seem to be the only reviewer, so hopefully the next 4(?) reviewers will decide that it now looks OK and my "vote" will get overruled.

Comment: FWIW, although I have never used this technology, the fact that the answer "looks" like it should be correct, and fact that the OP says it was exactly what they needed, I'm thinking that the answer should be upvoted.